# Openstack nova list create problems

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy server and installed All openstack components, I succesfully did glance image-list, But when i tried to do nova list i got following error:

```
Error: HTTPConnectionPool(host='192.168.0.2',port=8774): Max retries exceeded with url: /v2/2344gh34gh234g34hj34g3j4gh34jgh34jgh34jg/servers/detail (caused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 111] Connection refused)
```

Here is my /var/nova/nova-api.log

```
2014-01-20 10:43:20.867 19646 INFO nova.wsgi [-] Stopping WSGI server
2014-01-20 10:43:20.867 20051 INFO nova.openstack.common.service [-] Caught SIGHERM stopping children
2014-01-20 10:43:20.867 19275 INFO nova.openstack.common.service [-] Child 20052 exited with status 1
```

Comment: Too little log. Is that all the log you get for the request??

Comment: Is user nova owns /etc/nova directory? 
I get a feeling it more about the directory permission.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure the nova services are running, that could be the problem.

You should have running these services:

```
sergio@cachiovm:/opt/stack/nova$ ps -ef | grep nova
root      4217  3217  0 10:44 pts/10   00:00:00 sg libvirtd /usr/local/bin/nova-compute     --config-file /etc/nova/nova.conf
sergio    4223  3236  0 10:44 pts/12   00:00:13 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/nova-cert     --config-file /etc/nova/nova.conf
sergio    4227  3273  0 10:44 pts/16   00:00:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/nova-xvpvncproxy --config-file /etc/nova/nova.conf
sergio    4231  3266  0 10:44 pts/15   00:00:07 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/nova-novncproxy --config-file /etc/nova/nova.conf --web /opt/stack/noVNC
sergio    4236  3238  0 10:44 pts/13   00:00:15 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/nova-network --config-file /etc/nova/nova.conf
sergio    4239  3264  0 10:44 pts/14   00:00:15 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/nova-scheduler --config-file /etc/nova/nova.conf
sergio    4241  3307  0 10:44 pts/18   00:00:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/nova-objectstore --config-file /etc/nova/nova.conf
sergio    4242  4217  0 10:44 pts/10   00:00:59 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/nova-compute --config-file /etc/nova/nova.conf
sergio    4245  3301  0 10:44 pts/17   00:00:13 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/nova-consoleauth --config-file /etc/nova/nova.conf
sergio    4246  3219  0 10:44 pts/11   00:01:26 /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/nova-conductor --config-file /etc/nova/nova.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the "nova-api" package installed.

I was following the install instructions and somehow I ended up with an /etc/init/nova-api.conf file but somewhere along the line nova-api was removed and it led to this useless error.

The bottom line: UPSTART SUCKS -- it really should report this kind of problem.  But error handling was never its strong suit.

Answer (score 0):

Start nova API in debug mode and you can see the actual error.

`nova-api --debug`

In my case the error was

`CRITICAL nova [-] RequiredOptError: value required for option: lock_path`

I have checked `lock_path` param in `/etc/nova/nova.conf` . it was not configured under `[DEFAULT]`. I have moved `lock_path` to `[DEFAULT]` . Then I started `nova-api` and worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in my case, while I am trying this on Ubuntu 14.04 and Juno on the below command I would get the status as below and the logs were frozen.

```
service nova-api start
```

> > > nova-api stop/waiting

For some strange reason nova-api had gone missing, reinstalling it fixed the problem.